# if-else conditions based on expect statement results

Tags: webdriver, mocha.js, testrail

I'm working towards testrail integrations, i want to update testrail after each test pass/fail. Lets day if i've a test like below

```
  it('rightpanel should exist', () => {
    //some logic or preparatory work
    expect(rightpanel.isLoaded()).to.be.true;
    // here i want to know whether above expect statement failed or passed.
    // based on it, i want to update test rail by making a webservice call
  });
```

we are using WDIO, is there a better way to integrate to testrail? No one replies on their community forum so, i'm asking here.

Comment: probably the code under expect won't be executed if it fails. You can understand by this :). I recommend to use the result after all tests are run

Answer (score 1):

With mocha you can use a [repoter](https://mochajs.org/#reporters) to manage the results of your tests.
The default reporter is [Spec](https://mochajs.org/#spec), but if you use [json-stream](https://mochajs.org/#json-stream) you can attach another process to this stream to send test reports to testrail while executing.

Otherwise, if you don't need to send them in *real time*, you can use the json reporter and parse them in a single call.

You can also check on github some existing reporter that connects directly to testrail:

- https://github.com/CommodoreBeard/mocha-testrail-advanced-reporter
- https://github.com/awaragi/mocha-testrail-reporter
- [complete list](https://github.com/search?q=mocha%20testrail)